# Random function in Racket

Tags: random, racket

Hello I have this function that makes randomly: a, b, c or d.

```
(define random-abcd
  (let ([n (random 4)])
    (cond [(equal? n 0) 'A]
          [(equal? n 1) 'B]
          [(equal? n 2) 'C]
          [else 'D])))
```

That means I have 4 possible random outputs. But I would like to build a recusrsive function that gives an output between a number I give as parameter.

For example:

random-my 3 -> gives and output between: a b or c

random-my 5 -> gives and output between: a b c d or e

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass a number `n` and you can do `(random n)` to get a random number `r` in the range `[0,n>`. Now The char number for `#\a` is `97` so if you do `(integer->char (+ 97 r))` you get `#\a` for `0`, `#\b` for `1`, ...

You can get a string with `(list->string (list #\a)) ; ===> "a"`.

You can get a symbol with `(string->symbol "a") ; ==> a`

I leave it to you to put it all together, however it's not recursive.

Comment: It's more readable (and portable, though I know this question is about Racket specifically) to use `(char->integer #\a)` instead of 97. Also, it's `integer->char`, not `number->char`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I always confuse `number` and `integer` in those procedures, so I've updated. `(char->integer #\a)` is the same as `97` in ascii and utf-8 starts with 7 bit ascii so it's not like you ever will get a different answer, but perhaps for clarity it might be better.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
(list-ref '(a b c d e f) (random 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

fun problem. one way i can think of to do this is to use a vector (since it's zero-indexed and random-access) and given a number, choose a random number smaller than that value. once you have the number, then use that as the index into the vector to get the character in the vector at that index. in essence, you're just randomly indexing into 'slices' of the vector and slice size is determined by input argument.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive fn to produce a random list of n letters till nth letter:

```
(define (f n (ol '()))
    (if (= n (length ol))
        ol
        (f n (cons (string (integer->char (+ 97 (random n)))) ol))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 5)
```

Output:

```
'("b" "d" "b" "e" "e")  ; list will have random letters;
```